# Calculations in $K$-Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, representation-theory

Suppose we have some field $K$ and non-zero elements $a,b,$ in $K$. Define $H=H(a,b)$ to be the $K$-algebra with basis $\{1,x,y,z \}$ over $K$ satisfying $$x^2=a, \\ y^2=b, \\ z=xy=-yx$$
**Question:** How can I express $xy, yz, z^2, xz$ and $zx$ as $K$-linear combinations of the basis elements $1,x,y,z$?

**My Problem:** Given we (surely) cannot assume the existence of $\sqrt{a}$ (in $K$) for example, how can we make such calculations? An arbitrary element of $H$ will take the form $\mu_1 1+ \mu_2 x + \mu_3 y + \mu_4 z$ but I'm not sure whether this is of much use. I think my issue is feeling uncomfortable with the notion of multiplying basis elements together and getting back an element of the field. I'm new to algebras and previous intuition (of for example vector spaces as sets of triple or n-tuples) leads me to think that multiplying elements of the vector space should yield another vector space element (as is the case with the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ for exmaple)

Any help and explanations would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that such an algebra exists? You could have an algebra *generated* by $\{1,x,y,z\}$ with the relations you've listed, but there's no guarantee that those generators will form a basis for the underlying vector space.  The polynomial algebra $k[x]$ is generated by $1, x$ but has infinite $k$-dimension.

Comment: I'm sure it must do since it's come from a (non-examined) exercise sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I see:

$xy = z$, so there's that.

$yz = y(-yx) = -y^2x = -bx$.  Similarly $xz = x^2y = ay$.

Finally $zx = (-yx)x = -yx^2 = -ya = -ay$.

Comment: Also, $z^2 = (xy)(-yx) = - x y^2 x = -b x^2 = -ab$.